# How to remove backslash in Django DB settings

Tags: python, django, pyodbc

I have been trying to link my mssql database to Django. When I run the Django server I get the error below. For normal query out of Django, it works fine, however, the Django doesnt even connect. My normal username when login into windows is `kmoh` from `EMEA` domain, when I normaly login into my windows account it looks like this: `EMEA\kmoh` but as you can see in the error it looks like this `EMEA\\kmoh`. So How can I remove this another backslash?

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 307, in get_new_connection
    timeout=timeout)
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'EMEA\\kmoh'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000]
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'EMEA\\kmoh'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")
```

I am using these:

- Windows 10
- django-pyodbc-azure: version 2.1
- Django 2.1
- Pyodbc: 4.0.25

my Django settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'xxx', #has been hide for this post
        'PORT': '1433',
        'NAME': 'BBL_Result',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to see the user and password set explicitly in the settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'USER': 'db_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
```

Comment: The problem is that the DB admin set the permission only on Windows Authentication.